# What was the scary code comment about dragons?

Tags: comments

The phrase was used as a warning that the code was pulling some serious stunts.
My google search for this is pulling up nada; but I remember someone doing a search of google source for the phrase quite a while back.

in lies dragons?

dragons sleep here...

Bah...

Comment: Remembering the google code was an edit. If I had remembered a bit sooner... double bah.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

[Here be Dragons.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_be_dragons)

originally sourced from [old maps](http://www.maphist.nl/extra/herebedragons.html), not that any old maps actually used the term!

PS. Not recommended to use the original latin "hic sunt dracones" unless you want to be really nerdy and appear superior to future code maintainers :)

Comment: Here there be dragons, yar!  (for talk like a pirate day).

Comment: Quidquid latine dictum sit, altum sonatur (whatever is said in Latin, sounds profound).

Comment: "Inveniam Viam Aut Faciemus" - We will find a way or make one (Upon facing those dragons)

Answer (score 9):

> #### // [Here be dragons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_be_dragons)

---

An example is in the source code of [HipHop for PHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HipHop_for_PHP), at [line 649 of /src/runtime/ext/ext_imagesprite.cpp](https://github.com/facebook/hiphop-php/blob/39415630e84538fb553cd325a85ce837bcf6cb70/src/runtime/ext/ext_imagesprite.cpp#L649) as of July 13, 2012:

```cpp
// Here be dragons. Thou art forewarned
```

If for some reason the programmer(s) doesn't quite understand what the code is doing, a comment saying "here be dragons" means that the code is "uncharted territory".

(*Note my username* `:P`)

Answer (score 5):

[Here be dragons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_be_dragons)

Answer (score 3):

"Here be dragons" is displayed when you go to about:config in the address bar in Firefox.

**Edit:** Please note I'm in the UK so this may be locale specific.

Comment: Disregard the previous comment--I just read through the source code, and it seems the "Here be dragons!" warning is shown in the en-GB localization, but not in en-US.

Comment: Here's the `config.dtd` file in Firefox 16.0.2, en-GB localization: http://pastebin.com/43yctp4f

Comment: *(continuation of previous comment)* The phrase "**Here be dragons!**" appears on line 41 of the above DTD file.  For en-US users, this phrase would be "**This might void your warranty!**"

Answer (score 1):

Search over GitHub repositories shows 1,904 occurrences of "Here be dragons": https://grep.app/search?q=Here%20be%20dragons.

Examples:

- [500 lines long notes about the multi-precision division in Golang](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/a9bb38222a06333176cafc5637083e0322277c09/src/math/big/natdiv.go#L5-L497)
- [clangd](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/d480f968ad8b56d3ee4a6b6df5532d485b0ad01e/clang-tools-extra/clangd/SourceCode.cpp#L53-L63)
- [kubernetes/kops](https://github.com/kubernetes/kops/blob/2f003d8e5664d403889c831a69578c74ebb93507/upup/pkg/fi/cloudup/populate_cluster_spec.go#L72-L81%20https://github.com/facebook/folly/blob/99fbca1df19fdd21f1b831cad6f50ece94573675/folly/experimental/symbolizer/SignalHandler.cpp#L420)
- [Twitter's Finangle](https://github.com/twitter/finagle/blob/develop/finagle-core/src/main/scala/com/twitter/finagle/server/ListeningStackServer.scala#L110-L120)
- [Chef](https://github.com/chef/chef/blob/2205419ad84a18881fc57fdb2ec3fe492228dcea/lib/chef/provider/package/snap.rb#L148-L169)